# Find if user prefers 12 / 24 Hour Clock?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I've got a drawRect that makes a timeline a bit like iCal. I use a for loop to write the times along a scroll view. I was wondering if A) theres a way of determining whether the user has chosen a 12 or 24 hour clock in the system settings and B) if there is a more efficient way of changing the time labels then calling an 'if' query every pass of the 'for' loop. 
Cheers

Comment: You need to be careful.  If the user has set 12/24 hour mode in Settings contrary to the locale, then NSDateFormatter (and likely some others) ignore the presence/absence of any `a` qualifier and provide (or not) the AM/PM value based on the 12/24 hour mode setting.  It's all quite screwy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSString *formattedString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:today dateStyle: kCFDateFormatterNoStyle timeStyle: kCFDateFormatterShortStyle];

NSRange foundRange;
foundRange = [formattedString rangeOfString:"am" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
if(foundRange.location == NSNotFound) {
    foundRange = [formattedString rangeOfString:"pm" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
}

BOOL isAMPMSettingOn = (foundRange.location != NSNotFound);
```

Answer (score 6):

The earlier answers assume that the "AM" and "PM" symbols are represented in roman characters. This code adapted from [keyur bhalodiya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22783218/72176) does a better job at handling languages like Chinese, by using the `AMSymbol` and `PMSymbol` methods of `NSDateFormatter`.

```
-(BOOL)uses24hourTime
{
     NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
     [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
     [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

     NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
     NSRange amRange = [dateString rangeOfString:[formatter AMSymbol]];
     NSRange pmRange = [dateString rangeOfString:[formatter PMSymbol]];

     return (amRange.location == NSNotFound && pmRange.location == NSNotFound);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];

if([[dateFormatter dateFormat] rangeOfString:@"a"].location != NSNotFound) {
    // user prefers 12 hour clock
} else {
    // user prefers 24 hour clock
}
```

Comment: This is actually the best answer, since many countries specify AM and PM as a.m. and p.m..

Comment: @Leuguimerius but some languages like Chinese use totally different characters for AM and PM. See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23621308/72176 for how to handle that.

Comment: @WilliamDenniss Brilliant! Solves everything. I had no idea such formatter existed.