# How can i get all the hours on the UIDatePicker?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uidatepicker

I have a `UIDatePicker` that is set to fr_FR so I have on the weel the numbers from `00` to `23`. When I select an hour I get the `English` format, if I pick , let's say, `19` , I would like to get `19:00` on the screen, but I get `07:00`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be prob in your dateformate you setdateformat:@"hh:mm" check as a bellow link

> [datePickerFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

check the bellow link may be its help more

[Setting NSDate in a "TimePicker" with 24 - 12 hours format xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257127/setting-nsdate-in-a-timepicker-with-24-12-hours-format-xcode)

Comment: Below which link ? I don't see any links (Invisible ? )