# uidatepicker 24hour formate in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, uidatepicker

I am Trying to assign the `24 hour` formate to `UIDATEPICKERVIEW` but i have not exactly idea to implement it.

in my **view.h** file

```
 @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *picker_alarm;
```

in my **view.m** file

```
picker_alarm.date=[NSDate date];
```

in my **.xib** file

i have taken uidatepicker and its **Mode** Property to **Time** in viewcontroller.

[image: Here is the my **Output**]

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151187/show-time-in-12-and-24-hour-format-in-uidatepicker-on-the-basis-of-app-settings** && **https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDatePicker/timeZone**

Comment: Possible duplicate of: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257127/setting-nsdate-in-a-timepicker-with-24-12-hours-format-xcode

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"NL"];
[picker_alarm setLocale:locale];
```

Comment: actually it does in the end. so thanks if(isTimeFormat12)
    {
        NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"US"];
        [self.dpTime setLocale:locale];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"UK"];
        [self.dpTime setLocale:locale];
    }

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the storyboard to change time format to 24 hour.

Follow these steps:

1. go to storyboard
2. select you datePicker
3. select attributes inspector
4. Change "Locale" property to English(Europe)

[image]

and in your code use following snippet:

```
NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
somelabel.text = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:_pickerDate.date];
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot force the date picker to show 24 hours time. That depends on the `locale` property

Doc says:

> UIDatePickerModeTime,           // Displays hour, minute, and optionally AM/PM designation depending on the locale setting (e.g. 6 | 53 | PM)

```
[datePicker setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
```

For testing this change the system time to 24hour mode. And check the picker in simulator

Comment: can you tell what to set the locale to get the 24 Hours time?

Answer (score 0):

*Create DatePicker with setting it **custom Locale***

```
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.time 
    datePicker.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "NL")  //or: Locale.init(identifier:en_GB") // using Great Britain
```

*Grab the time from above DatePicker,*

```
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    lblTime.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
```